# Заработок для джава джуниора

Tags: java

Слышал, что есть сайты, на которых студенты из зарубежья просят решить несложные задачи по Java (за символическую плату). Есть интерес не только учиться, но и помогать(?) и что-то на этом заработать. 
Кто-то знает подобные сайты? Поделитесь!

Comment: А чем обычные сайты фриланса не устраивают?
там тоже студентов по сезону хватает. а именно о сайтах по джаве и студентами на платной основе слышу впервые.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

загляните на [odesk](http://odesk.com), это все же самая известная биржа фрилансеров, там, наверняка, и  студентов и забугорья  немало, хотя, конечно, это именно фрилансерский ресурс, а не место пастбища нерадивых студентов, предлагающих порешать за них задачки.